# Batch: Copy a list (txt) of files ignoring extension

Tags: batch-file

I have the next batch file, but its matching by file name. This time the list I have is huge and has file names without extension, but can I ignore the extension and copy for example: filename.* to the destination folder?

This is the current script:

```
title Deploying Edithor
set src_folder=S:\ApliTelinver\Compilacion\Edithor 10.5\Pipe
set dst_folder=J:\alazarev\Objetos-Migracion-Pipe
set filelist=filelist-pipe.txt

echo Origen: %src_folder% >> "pipemigracion-!datetimef!.log"
echo Destino: %dst_folder% >> "pipemigracion-!datetimef!.log"
echo.
REM for /f %%i in (%filelist%) DO xcopy /S/E/U/Y "%src_folder%\%%i" "%dst_folder%" > "%dd%.log"
for /f "delims=" %%i in (%filelist%) do (
    xcopy /S/E/U/Y "%src_folder%\%%i" "%dst_folder%" >> "pipemigracion-!datetimef!.log"
)
echo Success. >> "pipemigracion-!datetimef!.log"
echo.
echo Done - Check log pipemigracion-!datetimef!.log
echo.
pause
goto start
```

Comment: Do all file names in the list have no extension or just some of them?

Comment: They have different extensions. All of them do, but different and all I have are list of filenames without the specific extension of each one.

Comment: @Andriy ya vam ostavil otvet. Spasiba!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I've understood the question. The file list, `filelist-pipe.txt`, contains file names, and all of the names are without extensions.

If so, you only need to append `.*` to the source file path in the `XCOPY` command:

```
title Deploying Edithor
set src_folder=S:\ApliTelinver\Compilacion\Edithor 10.5\Pipe
set dst_folder=J:\alazarev\Objetos-Migracion-Pipe
set filelist=filelist-pipe.txt

echo Origen: %src_folder% >> "pipemigracion-!datetimef!.log"
echo Destino: %dst_folder% >> "pipemigracion-!datetimef!.log"
echo.
REM for /f %%i in (%filelist%) DO xcopy /S/E/U/Y "%src_folder%\%%i" "%dst_folder%" > "%dd%.log"
for /f "delims=" %%i in (%filelist%) do (
    xcopy /S/E/U/Y "%src_folder%\%%i.*" "%dst_folder%" >> "pipemigracion-!datetimef!.log"
)
echo Success. >> "pipemigracion-!datetimef!.log"
echo.
echo Done - Check log pipemigracion-!datetimef!.log
echo.
pause
goto start
```

Please let me know if I'm still missing something.

Comment: yes you are right, it has to take the filename from the list and copy them from the `src_folder` matching by the filename and any extension of it. Still with `"%src_folder%\%%i.*"` is not working. Is not copying anything

Comment: Ya poproboval. Nu nichego se skopirovalo. Voobsheto ya uzhe probival dobavit `.*` v tomzhe samom meste.

Comment: Then I misunderstood the question. Please extend your post with: 1) a sample filename list, 2) sample contents of the source folder, 3) what is expected to be copied based on the list and the folder contents. Maybe someone will come up with the right idea faster than I.