# (OS X Shell) Copying files based on text file containing file names without extensions

Tags: macos, shell, file-copying

Preface: I’m not much of a shell-scripter, in fact not a shell-scripter at all.

I have a folder (`folder/files/`) with many thousand files in it, with varying extensions and random names. None of the file names have spaces in them. There are no subfolders.

I have a plain text file (`filelist.txt`) with a few hundred file names, all of them *without extensions*. All the file names have corresponding files in `folder/files/`, but with varying extensions. Some may have more than one corresponding file in `folder/files/` with different extensions.

An example from `filelist.txt`:

```
WP_20160115_15_11_20_Pro
P1192685
100-1373
HPIM2836
```

These might, for example, correspond to the following files in `folder/files/`:

```
WP_20160115_15_11_20_Pro.xml
P1192685.jpeg
100-1373.php
100-1373.docx
HPIM2836.avi
```

(Note the two files named `100-1373` with different extensions.)

I am working on an OS X (10.11) machine. What I need to do is **copy all the files in `folder/files/` that match a file name in `filelist.txt` into `folder/copiedfiles/`**.<sup>1</sup>

I’ve been searching and Googling like mad for a bit now, and I’ve found bucketloads of people explaining how to extract file names without extensions, find and copy all files that have no extension, and various tangentially related issues—but I can’t find anything that really helps me figure out how to do this in particular. Doing a `cp ˋcat filelist.txtˋ folder/copiedfiles/` would work (as far as I can tell) if the file names in the text file included extensions; but they don’t, so it doesn’t.

#### What is the simplest (and preferably fastest) way to do this?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> What I need to do is exactly the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959544/batch-copy-a-list-txt-of-files-ignoring-extension), but that one is specifically asking about [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), which is a very different kettle of sea-dwellers.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
while read filename
do
  find /path/to/folder/files/ -maxdepth 1 -type f \
 -name "$filename*" -exec cp {} /path/to/folder/copiedfiles/ \;
done</path/to/filelist.txt
```

Comment: Having read up on the individual commands used, I agree: it should. For some reason, though, it doesn’t. It runs for a second or so, doesn’t give any error messages, but also doesn’t actually copy any of the files. If I try (inexpertly) to debug by adding a second `-exec ls {} \;` argument, that doesn’t do anything either, nothing is output. I must be missing something crucial here, but I don’t know what. All folder paths should have trailing slashes and escaped spaces, right?

Comment: Right, managed to get it to work. The problem was that the text file had Windows CRLF line endings, rather than Unix LF ones, so `$filename.*` expanded to `100-1373\r.*`, which of course didn't exist. Switching to LF line endings fixed it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That was indeed a brilliant improvisation.